# RSepc test shows 'pending' but I don't have a pending command

Tags: ruby, rspec

I just picked up a RSpec book to read and I have this example, all in one file:

```
class RSpecGreeter
  def greet
    'howdy purdy'
  end
end

describe 'RSpec Greeter' do
  it 'should say howdy purdy when it receives the greet() message'
    greeter = RSpecGreeter.new
    greeting = greeter.greet
    greeting.should == 'howdy purdy'
end
```

So when I run it the book says it should pass and it makes sense, it should pass. But for me it shows as "pending"

> Pending:   RSpec Greeter should say howdy purdy when it receives the
>   greet() message
>       # Not yet implemented
>       # ./greeter_spec.rb:8
>
> Finished in 0.00012 seconds 1 example, 0 failures, 1 pending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you did not wrap the it statement in a block. To correct this you write

```
describe 'RSpec Greeter' do
  it 'should say howdy purdy when it receives the greet() message' do
    greeter = RSpecGreeter.new
    greeting = greeter.greet
    greeting.should == 'howdy purdy'
  end
end
```

For more on [pending examples](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Pending-Examples).

And more advanced examples of [pending tests](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples) as well.